# Hibernate annotation mapping, complicated diagram

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have some big problems with making a proper mapping for delivered diagram. It looks like this:

[image: diagram]

Now, so far I did this, hopefully its ok (ommited getters/setters). You'll notice that `USERS` has `DOMAIN_ID`, ignore it as it is not full diagram.

**FunctionalityGroup**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FUNCTIONALITY_GROUP")
public class FunctionalityGroup implements Serializable
{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "FUNCTIONALITY_GROUP_ID")
private Long functionalityGroupId;

@Column(name = "FUNCTIONALITY_GROUP_NM")
private String functionalityGroupName;

@Column(name = "FUNCTIONALITY_GROUP_DESC")
private String functionalityGroupDesc;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "funcionalityGroupId")
private List<Functionality> functionalityList;
}
```

**Functionality**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FUNCTIONALITY")
public class Functionality implements Serializable
{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "FUNCTIONALITY_ID")
private Long functionalityId;

@Column(name = "FUNCTIONALITY_NM")
private String functionalityGroupName;

@Column(name = "FUNCTIONALITY_DESC")
private String functionalityGroupDesc;

@Column(name = "FUNCTIONALITY_GROUP_ID")
private Long funcionalityGroupId;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "ROLE_FUNCTIONALITY",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "FUNCTIONALITY_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID")})
private List<Role> roleList;
}
```

**Role**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ROLE")
public class Role implements Serializable
{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ROLE_ID")
private Integer roleId;
@Column(name = "ROLE_NM")
private String roleName;
@Column(name = "ROLE_DESC")
private String roleDesc;
@Column(name = "OBJECT_TYPE")
private String objectType;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "roleList")
private List<Functionality> functionalityListy;
}
```

**Users**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class Users implements Serializable
{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "USER_ID")
private Long userId;
@Column(name = "USER_DESC")
private String userDesc;
@Column(name = "FIRST_NM")
private String firstNM;
@Column(name = "LAST_NM")
private String lastNM;
@Column(name = "IS_ENABLED")
private String isEnabled;
}
```

I have no idea how Role_Member and Role_Member_Entry should be mapped and handled withing object world, could somebody give me some hits? Thanks!

Normally I'd connect Users with Role as Many to Many, but the entity Role_Member_Entry ruins everything.

Comment: do you need role_member? you have the same fk constraints in role_member_entry

Comment: As I mentioned above, I did not made this diagram. I only need to map it :)

Comment: yeah I didnt know if you needed to map it exactly or not. As it currently is set it doesnt make a lot of sense. I can see either dropping the first join table or adding a pk to it and referencing it in the second with the extra column.

Comment: So you propose is to complain to team developing sql, that they should fix it?

Comment: I wouldn't complain, I would strongly suggest fixing that mapping. It would be a pain to ensure things worked correctly especially on inserts and deletes, let alone if you needed to add any constraints on those fields.